# How do I call an interstitial ad to load on another UIViewController?

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, admob

I have a UIViewController with a UIView displayed on it; pressing a button on the UIView *loads* my interstitial ad. When the UIView is subsequently displayed, I want the interstitial to be displayed with the rootVC as the UIViewController.

However, this code does not seem to work as intended:

1) My View Controller:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

let button: UIButton = {
    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    btn.setTitle("BUTTON", for: .normal)
    btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showUIView), for: .touchUpInside)
    return btn
}() 
@objc func showUIView(_ sender: UIButton) {
let popUp = MyUIView()
self.view.addSubview(popUp)
}
```

2) My UIView:

```
class MyUIView: UIView {

var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

let button: UIButton = {
let btn = UIButton()
btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
btn.setTitle("UIVIEW BUTTON", for: .normal)
btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(prepareInterstitial), for: .touchUpInside)
return btn
}()

@objc func prepareInterstitial(_ sender: UIButton) {
    interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
    let request = GADRequest()
    interstitial.load(request)

dismissPopUp()

if interstitial.isReady {
  interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: MyViewController())
       }
  }
```

I get this in the console:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <GADFullScreenAdViewController: 0x7f8611e22fc0> on <Project.MyViewController: 0x7f8612884800> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!`
```

which I do not understand because MyViewController is still very much a part of the view hierarchy.

I'd be really grateful if someone could show me how to fix this error, I'm relatively new to coding and not sure what I am doing wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this doesn't work is because you are creating a *brand new* VC here:

```
interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: MyViewController())
```

This `MyViewController()` is not the VC that is shown on the screen! You just created by calling its initialiser.

You need to somehow get the VC that's shown on the screen. One simple way to do this is to add a `rootVC` property to your `MyUIView`:

```
weak var rootVC: UIViewController?
```

And then present this instead:

```
if let rootVC = self.rootVC { // nil check!
    interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: rootVC)
}
```

In `showUIView`, set `self` as `rootVC`:

```
@objc func showUIView(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let popUp = MyUIView()
    popUp.rootVC = self
    self.view.addSubview(popUp)
}
```